# Searching friends alphabetically in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How should be query to select friends like:

users table

```
+--------+--------------+-------------+
|   id   |  first_name  |  last_name  |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
| 1      | John         | Doe         |
| 2      | Andrew       | Quin        |
| 3      | Sara         | Cambel      |
| 4      | Samanda      | Mint        |
| 5      | Bill         | Smith       |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
```

friends table

```
+--------+---------------+---------------+
|   id   |  user_one_id  |  user_two_id  |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
| 1      | 1             | 2             |
| 2      | 1             | 5             |
| 3      | 1             | 4             |
| 4      | 1             | 3             |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
```

When we search "s" in friends of user with id 1 the result should be:

```
| 4      | Samanda      | Mint        |
| 3      | Sara         | Cambel      |
| 5      | Bill         | Smith       |
```

"Samanda Mint" is first in list because "s" character is in first position, the same for "Sara Cambel", "Sam" is alphabetically ahead of "Sar".

"Bill Smith" is third because it contains "s" character, but "s" position is later then in previous names.

"Andrew Quin" is not in the result because there are no "s" character in name.

current query

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name 
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=f.user_two_id
WHERE f.user_one_id=1 AND LOWER(u.first_name || ' ' || u.last_name) LIKE :query;
```

Comment: Show the query you've come up with so far.

Comment: @eurotrash I added current query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an auxiliary column `full_name`

```
select u.id, first_name, last_name
from users u
join friends f on user_two_id = u.id,
lower(concat(first_name, last_name)) full_name
where user_one_id = 1
and full_name like '%s%'
order by position('s' in full_name), full_name;

 id | first_name | last_name 
----+------------+-----------
  4 | Samanda    | Mint
  3 | Sara       | Cambel
  5 | Bill       | Smith
(3 rows)
```

Comment: when I see this answer I at last understand the question - thank you